# Bean Validation with JBoss Errai

Tags: validation, maven, gwt, bean-validation, errai

I want to make a GWT app with the Errai framework but I run in some problems with the Data Binding and Validation.

My pom.xml

```
<dependency>

  <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>

  <artifactId>errai-validation</artifactId>

  <version>${errai.version}</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>

  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>

  <scope>provided</scope>

</dependency>

<dependency>

  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>

  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>

  <classifier>sources</classifier>

  <scope>provided</scope>

</dependency>

<dependency>

  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>

  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>

  <version>4.2.0.Final</version>

  <scope>provided</scope>

</dependency>

<dependency>

  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>

  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>

  <version>4.2.0.Final</version>

  <scope>provided</scope>

  <classifier>sources</classifier>

</dependency>
```

My app.gwt.xml includes the Errai-Validation and HibernateValidator modules:

```
<inherits name="org.jboss.errai.validation.Validation" />
<inherits name="org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator" />
```

There are no unresolved dependencies I have already double checked this.

When I try to run the application with mvn gwt:run I'm getting the following error:

```
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.exception.UnsatisfiedDependenciesException:  @> org.jboss.errai.ui.nav.client.local.Navigation
- field org.jboss.errai.codegen.meta.MetaField:org.jboss.errai.ui.nav.client.local.Navigation.stateChangeEvent could not be satisfied for type: org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.lifecycle.api.StateChange
Message: can't resolve bean: org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.lifecycle.api.StateChange<java.lang.Object> ( @Default )
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.AsyncGenerators$FutureWrapper.get(AsyncGenerators.java:112)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.AsyncGenerators$FutureWrapper.get(AsyncGenerators.java:86)
    at org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.AbstractAsyncGenerator.startAsyncGeneratorsAndWaitFor(AbstractAsyncGenerator.java:100)
    at org.jboss.errai.ioc.rebind.ioc.bootstrapper.IOCGenerator.generate(IOCGenerator.java:58)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator.java:40)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:657)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:79)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:276)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ShellModuleSpaceHost.rebind(ShellModuleSpaceHost.java:141)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebind(ModuleSpace.java:595)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:465)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
    at com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT.create(GWT.java:57)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:85)
    at org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Container.bootstrapContainer(Container.java:64)
    at org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Container.onModuleLoad(Container.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:406)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Thats why the Bootstrap is failing and the application is throwing a onModuleLoad Exception and is not starting.

If I remove the 2 validation modules I'm able to start the application without any errors.

Im using the Errai Tutorial with version 3.0.1 FINAL.

Thanks for your help :)

---

EDIT:

I resolved the error by adding

```
<inherits name="org.jboss.errai.ui.nav.Navigation" />
```

to my app.gwt.xml but now I'm running into the next problem with this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'org.jboss.errai.validation.client.ValidatorFactoryImpl$GwtValidator' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)    
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)     
at com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT.create(GWT.java:57)   
at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:85)   
at org.jboss.errai.validation.client.ValidatorFactoryImpl.createValidator(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:11)     
at com.google.gwt.validation.client.AbstractGwtValidatorFactory.getValidator(AbstractGwtValidatorFactory.java:90)   
at org.jboss.errai.validation.client.ValidatorProvider.get(ValidatorProvider.java:37)   
at org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.BootstrapperImpl$28.getInstance(BootstrapperImpl.java:432)    
at org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.BootstrapperImpl$28.getInstance(BootstrapperImpl.java:1)  
at org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.container.IOCDependentBean.getInstance(IOCDependentBean.java:96)  
at org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.container.IOCDependentBean.getInstance(IOCDependentBean.java:87)  
at org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.container.SyncToAsyncBeanManagerAdapter$1.getInstance(SyncToAsyncBeanManagerAdapter.java:148)     
at org.jboss.errai.ui.nav.client.local.spi.GeneratedNavigationGraph$2.produceContent(GeneratedNavigationGraph.java:69)  
at org.jboss.errai.ui.nav.client.local.Navigation.maybeShowPage(Navigation.java:304)    
at org.jboss.errai.ui.nav.client.local.Navigation.navigate(Navigation.java:249)     
at org.jboss.errai.ui.nav.client.local.Navigation.navigate(Navigation.java:230)     
at org.jboss.errai.ui.nav.client.local.Navigation.navigate(Navigation.java:225)     
at org.jboss.errai.ui.nav.client.local.Navigation.goTo(Navigation.java:191)     
at org.jboss.errai.ui.nav.client.local.DefaultNavigationErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultNavigationErrorHandler.java:27)     
at org.jboss.errai.ui.nav.client.local.Navigation.goTo(Navigation.java:193)
```

Is there another module that is missing?

I'm correct that Errai is creating the ValidationFactory and injecting the correct instance? So I don't have to create my own ValidationFactory like here:

[GWT Validation Tutorial](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideValidation.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's correct. You don't have to create your own ValidationFactory. Errai will do that for you. You can simply @Inject a Validator.

I have prepared a version of the Errai tutorial using 3.0.1.Final that shows exactly that (following the instructions from the [reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/errai/3.0.1.Final/errai/reference/html_single/#sid-51282340_DataBinding-Beanvalidation)). I've put the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/csadilek/errai-tutorial/tree/validation).

The last error you pasted doesn't contain enough information to investigate why this is failing for you. However, you should see more error information in the devmode console.

Comment: Does Errai validation work with latest GWT and Errai, namely 2.7.0 and 3.1.1.Final? Or does Errai 3.1.1.Final even works with 2.7.0 version of GWT?